# Why copy method of std::string in C++ is showing weird behavior in this program?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string str1 = "geeksforgeeks is for geeks";   
    string str2 = "geeksforgeeks is for geeks";

    char ch1[100];
    char ch2[100];
 
    cout<<str1.size()<< endl << endl;
    str1.copy(ch1,23,0);
    str2.copy(ch2,24,0);
    
 
    cout << ch1 << endl << endl;
    cout << ch2 << endl << endl;
    


    return 0;

}
```

The length of string is 26, when I tried to copy more than 23 characters, it is showing weird behavior (printing random character in the last)
Here is the output of the above program

> ```
> 26
>
> geeksforgeeks is for ge
>
> geeksforgeeks is for gee£qí╜∙⌂
> ```

Comment: ["The resulting character string is not null-terminated. "](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `char[]`'s are uninitialized and you don't place a `\0` at the end of the strings after the copy.

Another solution is to initialize the `char[]`'s at construction:

```
char ch1[100]{};
char ch2[100]{};
```

Comment: @Human That's undefined behavior in effect. The `char[]` probably has 24 bytes of `\0` (even though it's uninitialized) for some reason out of your control.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you haven't set any '\0' (null) character to determine the end. That's why it's picking up garbage value.

you can do

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string str1 = "geeksforgeeks is for geeks";   
    string str2 = "geeksforgeeks is for geeks";

    char ch1[100];
    char ch2[100];
 
    cout<<str1.size()<< endl << endl;
    str1.copy(ch1,23,0);
    str2.copy(ch2,24,0);
    
    ch1[23] = '\0';  
    ch2[24] = '\0';  
 
    cout << ch1 << endl << endl;
    cout << ch2 << endl << endl;
    


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add null-terminator `char` by yourself; while [`std::string::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) doesn't do that.

E.g.

```
str1.copy(ch1,23,0);
ch1[23] = '\0';
str2.copy(ch2,24,0);
ch2[24] = '\0';
```

Comment: But why it works when we copy 23 characters or less? Why then the extra characters are not printed?

Comment: @Human The behavior of printing out a non null-terminated `char*` is undefined.

Comment: @tarunmali `ch1` and `ch2` are not initialized and contain indeterminate values for each index due to that. So one of the chars in `ch1` and `ch2` might be `\0`. In your example, `ch1` might have a `\0` after `for ge`, but that's not guaranteed. And even if it is a `\0` it is still an indeterminate value that happens to be `\0`, but at the point, that value is read (when you are printing it) you encounter undefined behavior.